# List object versions from AWS S3 in .NET 6

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a simple code to get versions of a file from S3 but getting the error below. In the meantime, put and get object requests for the same files are working fine.

```
var getVrRequest = new ListVersionsRequest()
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            MaxKeys = 10
        };
        ListVersionsResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = await client.ListVersionsAsync(getVrRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
```

ex.Message = "There is no such thing as the ?versions sub-resource for a key"

Any idea what might be the problem for getting this error?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Er60.png)

Comment: Is the S3 bucket versioning-enabled?

Comment: What does bucketName contain?  The bucket name, or a bucket name and key?

Comment: the bucket versioning is enabled.
bucketName is the bucket name. With the same bucket name I put files and read files as well

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. For put and get objects, for the request BucketName property I was using the whole path starting with the bucket name and I thought it's the same thing here, but for list versions request, it should be only the name of the bucket.